# Joomla Meta Title "reset to default"

Tags: seo, joomla

I'm having trouble figuring out why the meta title of a website I'm managing comes up as "reset to default" on Google.

Please see below for screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SERP link looks fine from here...

[image]

It is likely that you are hitting a set of servers that are not up to date yet. Just be patient. It will all work out okay.